# Cancel Backspace back in all dynamic iframe pages recursively

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, iframe

My asp.net application contains iframe element named "bodyFrm".
bodyFrm content changes dynamically, the content pages contains iframe and more html elements.
sometime the child page contains iframe with more child page.
I want to cancel the action go to previous page when user pressed the backspace.
I try to call CancelBackspace functoin in window.onkeydown event of main page,
but it's called sometimes,not for every key press,
how can I call the function for every key press in application ?
I can't use jquery.

in main page, works part time:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.onkeydown = CancelBackspace();
function CancelBackspace(e){
  if(!e)
     e = event;
  if(e.keyCode == 8)
     return false;
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can prevent the back space key operation with this

```
document.onkeydown=function(event){

                switch (event.keyCode) {
                    case 8 :
                     {
                        if (!event)
                            event = window.event;
                        // FOR IE9 & Other Browsers
                        if (event. preventDefault) {
                            event. preventDefault();
                        }
                        //FOR IE8 and Lower
                        else {
                            event.returnValue = false;
                            event.keyCode = 0;
                        }
                     }
                        break;
                }
            };
```

Comment: your not passing `event` to your keydown handling function above